# Charting & Trading platform with 3rd party integration

Tags: programming, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, charts, broker

so it's 2020 and I'm surprised that there don't seem to be any platforms that provide clear and easy integration with a 3rd party backend for indicator/signal generation, charting, trade execution, trade tracking, and all of the rest of the things that we use a brokerage's platform for.

I've got to be missing something.

after a fair bit of research, it seems that only Interactive Brokers truly provides something close to what I'm describing, but from their docs it isn't clear whether or how to integrate this into the TWS platform for charting custom indicators generated in 3rd party software.

Alpaca should do this, but they seem to be dependent on TradingView's charting engine which itself has made the mistake of using a custom scripting language, as did TOS, to the exclusion of richer languages like R, Python, C++ and the like.

Please tell me that I'm wrong and that there is a platform that will allow me to do the following 4 things:

1) Stream live market data (Equity, Options, Indices, ETFs, Futures, etc.)
2) Access this data in 3rd party software without any language restrictions
3) Chart Indicators generated by the 3rd party software within the charting platform
4) Execute & track trades via the 3rd party software

Comment: I think you need to think about vendor intent in offering things like this, even those that charge a fee.  It's to make money.  IB's TWS is geared toward retail/day-traders with a basic tool set and limited historical data, since adding more bells and whistles doesn't really make them money.  I think most that trade professionally, or at least make a living off of it, either do it through an institution (who has built its own tools and infrastructure) or create their own tools (ie, backtesting, data, execution via through a broker API or directly w the exchange via FIX if more sophisticated)

Comment: @chris, you make a good point, generally. What I'm asking about, however, isn't more bells and whistles, but rather just exposing a genuine json/xml api for interaction with 3rd party software. IB has done half of what I'm looking for by providing a robust data api, but a charting api seems to be lacking from the community. Given the rise of the use of algos in retail trading, open source software, and the general accessibility of custom tooling, this vacancy seems odd. honestly, I think that I just haven't found it yet, because it's need appears so obvious.